# Getting No service for type has been registered error when trying to configure conditional dependency

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I have a .NET Core worker project. In the project I have implemented the repository pattern. My parent interface is `ISenderService` and I have only one method in that interface defined like this:

```cs
public interface ISenderService
{
    Task<bool> SendNotification(Notification notificationData);
}
```

Now I have implemented this interface for sending Email and SMS in `EMailService` and `SMSService` class:

```cs
public class EmailService : ISenderService
{
    public Task<bool> SendNotification(NotificationData notificationData)
    {
        // sms logic
    }
}

public class SmsService : ISenderService
{
    public Task<bool> SendNotification(NotificationData notificationData)
    {
        // sms logic
    }
}
```

Now I have an actual implementation class where based on a condition I want to instantiatiate either EmailService or SMSService class like this way  for thsi I created a service factory class and inside that service factory calss I am conditionally instantiating required class object .The implementation is like tis way

```cs
public interface ISenderServiceFactory
{
    ISenderService CreateService(int type);
}

public class SenderServiceFactory : ISenderServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public SenderServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public INotificationSenderService CreateService(int type)
    {
        ISenderService _senderService;
        if (type == 1)
        {
            _senderService = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<EmailService>();
        }
        else
        {
            _senderService = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SmsService>();
        }
        return _senderService;
    }
}
```

In implementation class I have done dependency injection like this

```cs
public class PublisherConsumer : IConsumer<NotificationPublishEvent>
{
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ISenderServiceFactory _senderServiceFactory;
    
    public PublisherConsumer(
        ISenderServiceFactory senderServiceFactory, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _senderServiceFactory = senderServiceFactory;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NotificationPublishEvent> context)
    {
        try
        {            
            int type = 1;
            ISenderService _senderService =
                _senderServiceFactory.CreateService(type);
            //other logic
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

In program.cs I have configured like this

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ISenderServiceFactory, SenderServiceFactory>();
```

But still I am getting error:

> No service for type 'Notification.Worker.Repositories.EmailService' has been registered

Comment: Why do you expect that registering `ISenderServiceFactory` will magically register `IEmailService` and `ISmsService` for you? Did you even read the error message?

Comment: @IanKemp what do you think ? I am posting the error meesage based on my imagination

Comment: So did you try actually registering other services? Like
`services.AddSingleton<EmailService>();`
`services.AddSingleton<SmsService>();`

Comment: @Alexander I have tried this on services.AddSingleton<EmailService>();

Comment: You need to register all the service instead of only the factory service.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following two registrations:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<SmsService>();
services.AddSingleton<EmailService>();
```